# Simulating a system of nonlinear ODEs?

Tags: programming

I was trying to simulate a system of ODEs on Mathematica in an effort to try to understand how to muck around with Mathematica but for some reason the following lines of code do not yield any results; the code just seems to run without conclusion. Could anyone shed some light on why this is happening perhaps?

```
system = {x'[t] == x[t] + y[t], y'[t] == z[t], z'[t] == x[t] * y[t]};
sol = DSolve[system,{x,y,z},t]
```

Is it perhaps an erroneous call and/or usage of the DSolve command? Is it not meant for use on non-linear equations?

Comment: It is since Mma does not know the exact solution of this system of equations. If you add the initial values, replace `DSolve` by `NDSolve` and put a time interval instead of `t`, you will get a solution.

Comment: Thanks! Thought as much but was still wondering if there was some fancy stuff happening within mathematica which created a new object that I can then use for further calculations.